# How to checkin interceptor whether a controller triggered a redirect

Tags: spring, redirect, httpresponse, interceptor

In my Spring MVC project I added an interceptor class, to check, whether a redirect has been triggered.

Here is my controller-class:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectTesterController {

    @RequestMapping (value="/page1")
    public String showPage1(){

        return "page1";
    }

    @RequestMapping (value="/submit1")
    public String submitPage1(){

        return "redirect:/page2";
    }

    @RequestMapping (value="/page2")
    public String showPage2(){

        return "page2";
    }

}
```

So if I call e.g.

> localhost:8080/MyContext/submit1

the method "submitPage1" is executed.

Now - the server tells the client, to call

> localhost:8080/MyContext/page2

which is also working.

So - I want to step into that process, after method "submitPage1"has been executed. 
In my mind there should be some order/command in the httpResponse, which I could ask.

To check that, I made a breakpoint in my interceptor class in the method: "postHandle" - bit since then, I have no idea how to continue.
I tried to read the outputStream - but doing so crashes my application. (leads to an exception --> outputStream has already been called..).

Isn't there an easy solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Following example shows how to test if a view is a `redirect`:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                                   ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
                if (modelAndView != null && StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(modelAndView.getViewName(), "redirect:")) {
                    // handle redirect...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See: [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html), [StringUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html)

Spring MVC Documentation: [Intercepting requests with a HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)